# Adding 1 to very small numbers

Tags: matlab, floating-point, numbers, addition

I have a question about adding the number 1 to very small numbers. Right now, I am trying to plot a circular arc in the complex plane centered around the real number 1. My code looks like:

```
arc = 1 + rho .* exp(1i.*theta);
```

The value `rho` is a very small number, and `theta` runs from 0 to pi, so whenever 1 is added to the real part of `arc`, MATLAB seems to just round it to 1, so when I type in `plot(real(arc),imag(arc))`, all I see is a spike instead of a semicircle around 1. Does anyone know how to remedy this so that MATLAB will not round 1 + real(arc) to 1, and instead conserve the precision?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the exact code that demonstrates this problem? Not really any way to give a definitive solution unless we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Bitwise, sorry if you were offended by my downvote! But I don't think that I was the only person who didn't understand the relevance of your answer. I downvoted (and added a comment explaining why), you updated with a fuller explanation, and now everyone reading this understands your point better. Seems like an example of the community working to me.

Comment: @DanBecker No problem and no hard feelings - my fault for not clarifying how the answer is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

`rho=1e-6; theta=0:pi/100:pi; arc=1+rho*exp(1i.*theta); plot(arc); figure(); plot(arc-1);`

Shows, that the problem is in plot, not in loss of precision. After `rho<1e-13` there will be expected trouble with precision.

The two other possible misconceptions:
 - doubles have finite precision. 16 decimal digits or 1+2^-52 is the limit with doubles.
 - format short vs. format long -- matlab shows by default only 6 or 7 digits

It also happens to be that 6-7 digits is the limit of a 32-bit float, which could explain also that perhaps the plot function in Octave 3.4.3 is also implemented with floats.

Left: 1+1e-6*exp, Right: (1+1e-6*exp)-1 
[image]

Comment: The left is for 1e-6, I assume? In freemat I need get a similar picture with 1e-15, but not earlier.

Comment: Aki, is the code in your post the code that you used to generate the two plots you show? When I run that code, both plots look fine to me (R2012a on Windows 8).

Comment: Ah, I see that you are using Octave. So it appears that you have demonstrated a problem in Octave, but matlab appears to not have this problem.

Comment: @DanBecker Not quite. With MATLAB, I get no picture like the one on the left, but the half-circle starts becoming to narrow for `rho` between `1e-11` and `1e-12` (where it already looks quite "spiky"), so MATLAB's plot are somewhat unusual as well. (`plot(arc-1)` is still normal, as are both plots for these rho values in freemat, so I think Aki is on to something here.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a builtin solution for exactly this probem:

[exp1m()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm1.html)

[log1p()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log1p.html)

explicitly:

```
log(arc)=log1p(rho*exp(1i*theta))
```

to get what you need.

Of course you need to work in log space to represent this precision, but this is the typical way this is done.

Comment: Useful functions, but not relevant for this question (the argument of `exp` is not a small number here).

Comment: @DanBecker define eps=rho*exp(1i*theta) and then log(arc)=log1p(eps). I added it to the answer so it would be written explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In [double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples) representations, the smallest number strictly greater than `1` that can be represented is `1 + 2^-52`.

This is a limitation imposed by the way non-integer numbers are represented on most machines that can be avoided in software, but not easily. [See this question about approaches for MATLAB.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568922/matlab-precision)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Not in my octave... did you mean 1e-16 (which would be <`2^-53`)?

Comment: I mean rho=1e-6 as in my answer. The plot (arc) is staggered, while plot(arc-1) is smooth. Only after rho<1e-14 1+exp(i*theta) can't hold the precision as is expected. My Octave is 3.4.3.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Ok, I just checked the real value of arc(1) and arc(2) manually, never used octave's plot. With freemat I get great half-circles up to `rho=1e-13`.

Comment: While Aki's post is interesting, I strongly suspect that this is the real problem, and there is no real solution other than to decide to plot the arc around a more convenient point (like 0).