# MATLAB precision when substracting

Tags: matlab, precision, floating-accuracy, double-precision

I need high precision for a project I'm working on.
The problem I have is illustrated here when substracting:

```
>> 1-0.9999999999999999

ans = 1.1102e-16

>> 1-0.99999999999999999

ans = 0
```

I know it's related to the double precision. Is there anyway I could get a higher precision?
I checked the "vpa" function but I can't manage to get higher precision.
Could someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have an installation of Matlab's Symbolic Math Toolbox ?

Comment: Try `vpa('1-0.9999999999999999')` (note quotation marks). `vpa(1-0.9999999999999999)` won't work because `0.9999999999999999` is first converted to `double`

Comment: Minor note: `vpa` requires the Symbolic Math Toolbox, which High Performance Mark is inevitably referring to in the end. Also good job Luis!

Comment: There are other languages that provide arbitrary precision accuracy, like python.

Comment: there's also HPF by *John D'Errico*: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class, or the MEX-wrappers around GMP/MPFR by *Ben Barrowes*: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446-multiple-precision-toolbox-for-matlab

Comment: You could use `long double`'s in mex functions.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: unfortunately, [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double)'s are not necessarily portable, VC++ maps `long double` to simply `double`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx8xs15.aspx. Although in reality `double` computations are performed in 80-bit registers if done on the FPU (the native format of x87), but they are stored in 64-bit when transferred to memory. There is an instruction that affects whether intermediate results are reduced to 64-bit after each computation.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab internally uses the 64-bit system double for all its numbers, which explains the precision issues. There do exist extensions for matlab that allow you to use arbitrary precision arithmetic. See for example 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568922/).